# Server not reading files

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to create a new version of my website, in English.

Made a sub-domain for `/en` folder, ´en.artotek.fi´.
It didn't read my `ìndex.html` at first, but `index.php` worked.
The server's CP doesn't let me put file names (e.g index.html -> indexhtml).

I have style.css in the same folder, and properly linked, but it won't read it.

I've tried `link href`:

`*public/html/css/style.css*` 
and
`*style.css*`

```
public
 ->
   html (index.html)
      ->
        en (index.html)
```

I'd really like it to have a subdomain, so I can't put it in the same folder with my main index.html.

Pardon if my question is too unclear.

Any solutions?

Comment: What error code do you get? 404, 500, .. Do you have shell access?

Comment: @DanFromGermany No errors. The subdomain works, but shows only the PHP file without any CSS.

Comment: Can you open the styles with the browser? URL might be `/html/css/style.css` or `/css/style.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just been to http://www.artotek.fi/en/ and can see that there is no style sheet being successfully called. If this is the right domain then I can see a major problem stopping the stylesheet from being successfully called:

You currently have the following code

```
<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skel-noscript.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ftp://artotek@ftp.artotek.fi/public/html/css/style.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ftp://artotek@ftp.artotek.fi/public/html/css/style-desktop.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ftp://artotek@ftp.artotek.fi/public/html/css/noscript.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ftp://artotek@ftp.artotek.fi/public/html/css/style-mobile.css" >
</noscript>
```

May I suggest firstly moving the `<link>` tag out of the `<noscript>` tag.
Secondly, those URL's look a bit suspect. I dug around a bit and it looks to me like you want the following URL http://artotek.fi/css/style.css

So... my final suggestion: replace the above block with this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://artotek.fi/css/style.css" >
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://artotek.fi/css/style-desktop.css" >
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://artotek.fi/css/noscript.css" >
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://artotek.fi/css/style-mobile.css" >
```

Comment: The content which I have removed from this post is not appropriate. Please do not post that again.